# Dynamically change color of D3 Node (force directed graph)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors, nodes, fill

I'm trying to change the color of a node with a specific ID in D3, depending on what the user selects in a survey. I have this line of code:

```
$("#" + type).find("path, circle").attr("fill", "#333333");
```

where "type" is the name of the node I want to target (this name could change depending on the survey options selected, obviously). Looking at the console, the correct node is selected, but I just can't change the color. I've also tried .style("fill","#333333") instead of .attr("fill", #333333), but nothing seems to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the d3 way is this:

```
d3.select("#" + type).select("circle").style("fill", "#333333");
```

Comment: Where I'm trying to select the node is outside of my d3.js file, in an application.js file...that should still work though, right?

Comment: yes this should work from the console...i suspect the selection is not working can you put a working fiddle

Comment: Here's one fiddle...this is with my application.js...I don't know how to put multiple js files in one fiddle...https://jsfiddle.net/8vf4spdo/

Comment: in the code you are doing this `d3.select("#" + type)` but while making circle  you are not setting any id..so this `d3.select("#" + type)` will never work

Comment: Ah! I got it! Where I append my nodes I added .attr("id", function(d){return d.name}) and that did the trick. Thank you!!